# Show page if mysql value is met

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP, and I don't know a lot about it. I have had a go, but I don't know where I have gone wrong.

The code:

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['moderator'] {
    } else {
    header("location:noaccess.php");
}
?>
```

The error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in E:\LocalWebHost\htdocs\forum\test.php on line 4`

Comment: `... and $_SESSION['moderator']){ ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['moderator']) {
    } else {
    header("location:noaccess.php");
}
?>
```

In line 3, your if statement needs closing `)`.

Comment: How would I go about making it so if moderator = 1 in my mysql, it will let you access the page?

Comment: Ah, try changing your `if` statement to: `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['moderator'] == 1)`. I think this is more explicit. Are you setting $_SESSION['moderator'] anywhere?

Comment: @Martin Rudy answered your original question and what you're asking about "if something equals 1" is another question. You reposted the same one related to your comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799119/show-page-if-mysql-value-is-met and this question should be marked as solved instead of asking another question within the same one.